# Optimize an iteration through a numpy array for neighbours checking

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, optimization

Is there a way to optimize the following iteration with neighbours checking:

```
for i in range(1, A.shape[0]):
    for j in range(1, A.shape[1]):
        v = (A[i, j], A[i-1,j-1], A[i-1, j], A[i, j-1])
        if v == something: print(v)
```

where `A` is a (very big) numpy array of 0's and 1's, `v` and `something` are tuples (e.g. (0, 1, 0, 0)).

Comment: Well, I guess that's the problem of O(n^2) algorithms :)
It will always be relatively slow given very large n. I mean maybe you can make some domain specific optimizations (like do you really need to check all i,j combinations or is `ij==ji` in your case? Maybe you could use boolean masks for checking and definitely you could write your code in c or cython (sorry I know that's not what you mean).

Comment: @meow It's n^2 anyway, as the array itself is.

Comment: @user202729 ofc I never said anything about changing complexity :D

Comment: This look like some sort of convolution, so why not using built-in convolution   function. Even though that I'm not familiar with numpy and scipy, I'm pretty sure that they implement it in an efficient way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the test data first:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)
A = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(10, 8)).astype(np.uint8)
```

A:

```
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```

then create an array that use bits to represent neighbours value:

```
a = A[:-1, :-1] << 3
a |= A[:-1, 1:] << 2
a |= A[1:, :-1] << 1
a |= A[1:, 1:]
```

to check neighbours value of

```
11
00
```

you can use:

```
a == int("1100", 2)
```

the output:

```
array([[False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Note you can just say `0b1100` instead of `int("1100", 2)`.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is generate the four arrays of boolean conditions.  Roughly:

```
spot = A == v[0]
upleft = np.roll(A, (1,1), (0,1)) == v[1]
left = np.roll(A, 1, 1) == v[2]
up = np.roll(A, 1, 0) == v[3]
```

Then you can find the places where all four are true:

```
res = spot & upleft & left & up
```

This gives you a boolean array which is True wherever all the conditions are met.  You should ignore the first row and column, as they cannot be computed:

```
res = res[1:,1:]
# or
res[0,:] = False
res[:,0] = False
```

Comment: `np.logical_and.reduce` is better spelt `np.all` or just `spot & upleft & up & left`, which uses less memory.

Comment: @Eric: Can you explain why `&` uses less memory?

Comment: @JohnZwinck I think the `.reduce` operation - or `ufunc`s in general - cannot directly use array-like operands like your tuple `(spot, upleft, left, up)`, so it will first create an array of dimensions `(4, *spot.shape)` and then do the reduction.

Comment: @PaulPanzer: I did some tests with `%timeit`, and `&` is the fastest, `logical_and.reduce()` is significantly slower, and `np.all()` is the slowest.  I'm updating my answer to suggest `&` therefore.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the convolution based method suggested by @Matt.St in the comments.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scipy import signal
>>> a = np.random.randint(0, 2, (n, n))
>>> t = np.random.randint(0, 2, (2, 2))
>>> 
>>> 
>>> tt = 2*t[::-1, ::-1] - 1
>>> ts = t.sum()
>>> 
>>> result = signal.convolve2d(a, tt, 'valid') == ts
>>> 
>>> a
array([[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]])
>>> t
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 1]])
>>> result
array([[False,  True, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False, False, False,  True, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```